# Of which grammatical case is the „Menschen“ in the following sentence?

Tags: grammatical-case

In this sentence *Der Saal war voll Menschen.*
I am wondering:
Of which grammatical case is the *Menschen* here: the nominative, the genitive or the dative?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Adding an adjective to the noun makes it clearer:

> Der Saal war voll grüne**r** Menschen.

So we know it is genitive plural. It is even clearer if we use a noun whose genitive and dative plural forms are distinct:

> Der Saal war voll kleine**r** Kinder.

So it is definitely genitive plural.

Comment: Ist der Dativ nicht *grüne**n** Menschen*?

Comment: @CarstenS Hmm, stimmt. Ich hab mehr auf das Substantiv geachtet, und dabei gar nicht gemerkt, dass das Adjektiv ja auch wechselt …

Comment: @Jan : thanks for your answer; I found the following examples: ,,Die Straßen  lagen voll Schnee'' (from Duden); ,,Die Straßen lagen voller Schnee'' (from DWDS); would you consider the two as genitive constructions as well, with the genitive affix (Schnee-s) being omitted from explicit marking but UNDERSTOOD instead?

Comment: @Lynnyo *Schnee*, being a singulare tantum, works slightly differently, akin to words added onto *trotz*. I think I would understand *voll Schnee* to be in dative (but maybe it is nominative, I can’t think of an example where the cases would be different atm), which switches to genitive if an adjective is added: *voll gelben Schnees*.